# How to inegrate ioncube(or another extenstion) into phpbrew php version?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ioncube, phpbrew

I'm using phpbrew for switching between different versions of php. And now I can't install ioncube as php extension.
What I have already done:

- Download from http://www.ioncube.com/loaders.php my version of extension (Linux 64 tar.gz v6.0.9  2017-1-26)
- Unpack all and put ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so to `/home/kpot/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.24-last/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20131226`
- Add `extension=/home/kpot/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.24-last/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so` in php.ini
- Restart server with `sudo service apache2 restart`
- When apply **php -v** got this `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/kpot/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.24-last/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so' - /home/kpot/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.24-last/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20131226/ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so: undefined symbol: executor_globals in Unknown on line 0`
   after **phpinfo()** can't find anything associated with ioncube

Additional information:

- **uname -a** 
  `Linux KpoT 4.4.0-75-generic #96~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 11:06:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- **php -i | grep extension_dir**
  `extension_dir => /home/kpot/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.24-last/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20131226 => /home/kpot/.phpbrew/php/php-5.6.24-last/lib/php/extensions/debug-zts-20131226`
- phpbrew - 1.21.6

Answer (score 0):

First of all. When you unpack your archive with ioncube, pay attension to files with _ts at the end. In my case I have php with **thread safe** enabled(phpinfo()), so you must choose exactly that files.
Second problem occurs when php was compiled with **debug**. You must recompile your php without it.